# how to adjust sliding of scroll according to the value calculated by me?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on scroll. I have made a program wherein if the scroll box is in particular range of the panel then it automatically moves to a particular position in the slider.
For eg, I have a panel of size 500. the scroll has height of 100. Now the total intervals are 5. Now if i slide the scroll box at a position 225 then i want that it automatically slides to the start of that interval that is at position 200. or if i slide to position 450 then instead of staying there it goes to position 400.
Is it possible?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, in the same way that running your fingernails across a chalkboard is possible.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but I assume it's something to do with handling a scroll bar's Scroll event and forcing it to be set to some value other than what the user intended to set it to.  It's generally inadvisable to make controls behave in some weird, unexpected manner.